# iOS web view delegate methods are not getting called on Webpage navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Can not catch when web view change it's `url` without loading the page.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

This delegate method is getting called when loading the `webpage` for the first time.But after that if the `webpage` navigate on clicking of a button none of the delegate methods is getting called.If I load the page in  browser I can see the URL change. `Webpage` is using `History.pushState` to change the `URL`.

Comment: have you connected delegate to that webView w.r.t your view controller? And also imported delegate?

Comment: What you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: provide more code what you've tried with `UIWebView`

Comment: Yes I have connected my web view delegate  to my controller and that is the reason I got the delegate call for the first time loading the page.But on tapping any button on the webpage internal redirection is happing but "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" is not getting called.I want to detect any redirection happing in that page.